# HTML with Javascript - Validation does not work

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have the following HTML code for the simple form. As you can see there is a validation features included. But when I for example try to include email address without @ , it does not give any error. So validation simply fails. It would be really helpful if someone can give some hint.

**JavaScript**

```
<script language="Javascript">
    function validate(){
        var allok = true;
        if(useradd.1_New_User_Name_FirstLast__1.value == ""){
            alert('Invalid input for 1. New User Name (First,Last)');
            return false;
        }
        if(useradd.2_unix_username__2.value == ""){
            alert('Invalid input for 2. unix username');
            return false;
        }
        if(useradd.3_CAT_client_Name__3.value == ""){
            alert('Invalid input for 3. CAT client Name');
            return false;
        }
        if(useradd.4_Email_Address__4.value.indexOf("") == -1){
            alert('Invalid input for 4. Email Address, this must include "" character(s)');
            return false;
        }
        if(useradd.7_Requesters_Name_FirstLast__7.value == ""){
            alert('Invalid input for 7. Requesters Name (First,Last)');
            return false;
        }
        document.useradd.Submit.disabled="disabled";
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="useradd" method="Post" action="mailto:sholikar@yahoo.com" onSubmit="return validate();">
    <table width="100%" border="2" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>1. New User Name (First,Last):</td>
            <td><input type="edit" name="1_New_User_Name_FirstLast__1" value="" size="20"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2. unix username:</td>
            <td><input type="edit" name="2_unix_username__2" value="" size="10"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3. CAT client Name:</td>
            <td><input type="edit" name="3_CAT_client_Name__3" value="" size="20"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4. Email Address:</td>
            <td><input type="edit" name="4_Email_Address__4" value="" size="20"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign=top>5. Additional Access: </td>
            <td valign=top>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Xaccess__5" value="Yes">Xaccess<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Samba__5" value="Yes">Samba<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="CVS_Access__5" value="Yes">CVS Access<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Check-in_rights__5" value="Yes">Check-in rights<br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6. Additional requirement:</td>
            <td><input type="edit" name="6_Additional_requirement__6" value="" size="20"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7. Requesters Name (First,Last):</td>
            <td><input type="edit" name="7_Requesters_Name_FirstLast__7" value="" size="20"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset Form"></td>
            <td align="left"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: And where exactly does your code check for an `@` character in the email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Problem is, that the input-names are starting with numbers.

for example this:

```
...
<tr>
    <td>1. New User Name (First,Last):</td>
    <td><input type="edit" name="New_User_Name_FirstLast__1" value="" size="20"></td>
</tr>
...
```

and

```
...
if(useradd.New_User_Name_FirstLast__1.value == ""){
    alert('Invalid input for 1. New User Name (First,Last)');
    return false;
}
...
```

should solve your problem. if these changes aren't possible (due to an generated form or something else), you should use document.getElementById or HTML5 form Validation.

[Edit]

And of Course, the E-Mail Validation is wrong. Try this:

```
.value.indexOf("@") == -1
```

and it should work.

Comment: Hello Christian ..thanks for the reply. I tried the suggestions but it still does not work. I am posting the whole code here just for better understanding...

Comment: <script language="Javascript">
function validate(){
var allok = true;
  if(useradd.New_User_Name_FirstLast__1.value == ""){
    alert('Invalid input for 1. New User Name (First,Last)');
    return false;
  }...... document.useradd.Submit.disabled="disabled";
return true;
}
</script>
<form name="useradd" method="Post" action="mailto:sholikar@yahoo.com" onSubmit="return validate();">
<table width="100%" border="2" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<tr><td>New User Name (First,Last):</td><td><input type="edit" name="New_User_Name_FirstLast__1" value="" size="20"></td></tr>

Comment: Excuse me but somehow it started giving the very first validation error for the 1. New user name (when I insert no text) but it does not work for the subsequent fields. Any idea??

Comment: Heyy I figured it out ....Have to made similar changes in the rest of the fields as well. So ideally solution by Christian works. Thanks to all .

Answer (score 1):

> if(useradd.4_Email_Address__4.value.indexOf("") == -1){
>       alert('Invalid input for 4. Email Address, this must include "" character(s)');

I think you meant to put @ in the "" here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you working just with `JS` and `HTML`? Or are yoy embeding your code in ASP or something else?

`<script language="Javascript">` it's totally deprecated.

I also don't understand the dot notation in your JS:

```
useradd.1_New_User_Name_FirstLast__1
```

You should use:

```
document.getElementById("foo").value;
```